# Handling line replacements in headless mode

Tags: java, observable

I need something which will handle logging in commandline and headless mode as with a JFrame.

I have a library which uses a static reference to a `StyledDocument`.  I want to make it headless.  The problem is I need to make a way to universally handle Carriage Returns.  I am up to hear any solutions.

Here's my current code

```
if (data.contains("\b")) {
    Statics.ProgressDoc.remove(lastNewLine, Statics.ProgressDoc.getLength() - lastNewLine);
}
```

What I would like to do is convert it to just use a `String` and have the `JTextArea`'s content match whatever is in the string at all times.

In JavaFX UI objects, this can be accomplished with an `Observable` object.  Is there such an object in Swing for Text Areas?

Comment: Question 1: What do you mean by "logging"? Logging is already headless when done by the java.util.logging package. Question 2: Why are you using a StyledDocument? Are your log messages not plain text? Are you aware that a JTextArea uses a PlainDocument and does not show any styles? Question 3: You mention carriage returns, but your code is checking for `"\b"`, which is a backspace character. Is this intentional? Question 4: What does "universally handle Carriage Returns" mean? Question 5: When you say "convert it to just use a String" what does "it" refer to?

Comment: Ok, so basically, i'm trying to reform my current UI API, which sucks balls.   My logging class routes information to various parts of the application including the UI.   What I need is a way to attach an event listener to a string or some sort of object that will plug in to a JTextArea as easily as as a Commandline UI, or a JFXML UI, or even a Headless UI.   I need a way to have the UI monitor some string data.

Comment: A String is immutable, so String will never permit adding a listener to it (since its state never changes).  It sounds like you need an `addLogEventListener` method in your logging code, or possibly even an [addHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#addHandler%28java.util.logging.Handler%29) method.  The actual handler/listener should call JTextArea.append from within a Runnable passed to `EventQueue.invokeLater`.  A non-Swing handler/listener might just call BufferedWriter.write.